# Compare values from one excel workbook to another

Tags: excel-formula, phpexcel

I have two excel workbooks. `Workbook1` has list of urls and other i.e. `Workbook2` has along with list of urls few more columns.

Workbook1:

```
COLUMN A
url_list
url1
url2
url3
url
```

Workbook2:

```
COLUMN A                            COLUMN B         COLUMN C
Key Words                           URL              Jan 2015
Website search Engine Optimisation  url1             72614
Website search Engine Optimisation  url2             20890
Website search Engine Optimisation  url3             133968
Engine Optimisation                 url7             584625
```

I want to compare list of urls from `workbook1(Column A)` with `workbook2(Column B)`.

If any url from `workbook1` is missing in `workbook2` then it has to be added in `workbook2` in the end.

For example:
Now `url` is not present in workbook2, so it will be add , and will look like this
Workbook2:

```
COLUMN A                            COLUMN B         COLUMN C
Key Words                           URL              Jan 2015
Website search Engine Optimisation  url1             72614
Website search Engine Optimisation  url2             20890
Website search Engine Optimisation  url3             133968
Engine Optimisation                 url7             584625
                                    url
```

I am using library phpexcel to work with excel sheets in php in windows 7. 
Also is there any direct excel formula to do so?
I know with php i can do this.

Thanks

Comment: What you want to do is performing an action, more than evaluating a function. Even if the distinction is not always so clear-cut, in this case I guess you would need a VBA `Sub`.

Comment: other then VBA i cannot do in phpexcel ? and formula to just compare other functionality i thought in phpexcel

Comment: Most likely you can do it with PHPExcel. The operation you want to perform seems very basic. But I am not familiar with PHPExcel.

Comment: Did you find any answer useful?

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar task and i have been working tirelessly compiling some code. Though no comparison in-built functions exist, i get data from two different workbooks here (.xlsx files), retrieve specific columns from  two worksheets, strip off unnecessary stuff from the data, and store the values in two different associative arrays. I then can use in-built php functions to compare the arrays. You can then pick out the values you intend to write to a new worksheet. I still have to do more work pertaining to my task but i hope this helps someone some day.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php'; 

//set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');
//include_once 'Lib/PHPExcel.php';

$fileType = 'Excel2007';
$fileName = 'testBook.xlsx';
// Create new PHPExcel object
echo date('H:i:s') , " Create new PHPExcel object" , EOL;
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcelXX = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcelW = new PHPExcel();
// Read the file
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReaderXX = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelW, 'Excel2007');

$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objReaderXX->setReadDataOnly(true);
try {
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("Gemeinde_Bad_Rothenfelde.xlsx");
    $objPHPExcelXX = $objReaderXX->load($fileName);

    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $objWorksheetXX = $objPHPExcelXX->getActiveSheet();
    print($objWorksheet->getTitle());
    print($objWorksheetXX->getTitle());
//$objColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
//$objOtherCols = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
    $highestRow = $objWorksheetXX->getHighestRow();
    $gemendeHighest = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
    }catch(Exception $e) {
          die($e->getMessage());
    }

print("\n");
$arrayOrtStr = array();
$arrayGemStr = array();
$count = 1;
$i = 0;
//$colOrtXX is column in primus sheet, $colOrts is column in Gemeinde sheet,the numbers are the real column numbers in the sheets
for ($row = 1, $colOrtXX=1, $colOrtsT=7, $colOrtsTeil=2,$colStrXX=3, $colOrt=6,$colStr = 10; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    //$cell = $objWorksheet->getCell($objColumn.$row);
    //Getting cell values for Primus Sheet (Columns PostOrt,PostOrtsteil,PostStrasse)
    $cellOrtXX = $objWorksheetXX->getCellByColumnAndRow($colOrtXX,$row);
    $cellStrXX = $objWorksheetXX->getCellByColumnAndRow($colStrXX,$row)->setDataType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
    $cellOrtsTeil = $objWorksheetXX->getCellByColumnAndRow($colOrtsTeil,$row);
    $valOrtXX = $cellOrtXX->getValue();
    $valStrXX = $cellStrXX->getValue();
    $valOrtsTeil = $cellOrtsTeil->getValue();
    // Get cell values for Gemeinde sheet (Columns Ort and Strasse)
    $cellOrt = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($colOrt,$row);
    $cellStr = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($colStr,$row)->setDataType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
    //$cellOrtsT = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($colOrtsT,$row);
    $valOrt = $cellOrt->getValue();
    $valStr = $cellStr->getValue();
    // array populated for strasse column in gemeinde sheet but numbers stripped off the address
    $onlyStr = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/','',$valStr);
    $arrayGemStr[$i] = array("Strasse"=>$onlyStr);

    // Go through the Strasse column, only pick cells with Ort Bad Rothenfelde..compare and write
    if($valOrtXX == "Bad Rothenfelde"){
        // Creating associative array with Ortsteil and Strasse from Primus sheet
        $arrayOrtStr[$i] = array("OrtsTeil"=>$valOrtsTeil,"Strasse"=>$valStrXX);    
    }
    $i++;
    //print_r($array);
}

$ortTeil = array();
$contentFound = array();
$withStr = array();
foreach($arrayOrtStr as $arr) {
    $contentFound[] = $arr['Strasse'];
}
foreach($arrayOrtStr as $arr) {
    if(in_array($arr['Strasse'], $contentFound)){
            $ortTeil[] = $arr["OrtsTeil"];
            $withStr[] = $arr["Strasse"];
        }
    }

echo '<br/>========================================================<br/>';  
print_r($ortTeil);
print_r($withStr);




// Write the Excel file to filename some_excel_file.xlsx in the current directory
//$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcelW);
//$objWriter->save('Gemeinde_Bad_.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy ColumnA (excluding header/s) from Workbook1 and append to ColumnB of Workbook2 then apply Excel's Remove Duplicates to ColumnB of Workbook2. Removing duplicates should delete all entries from your example but you might blank out B2 (or maybe B1) from Workbook2 first to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I post here a very simple method.

This is not a "direct formula", but it may work for you.
I will assume your sources are `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` in the same workbook, it is easy to adapt to your needs.
Steps to follow:

1. **Add a helper column in `Sheet1`**:
   Enter formula `=IF(ISNA(MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5,0)),ROW(),100000)` in B2.
   Copy downwards. This will extract the row numbers of URLs to be copied, using a number larger than those for the rest (100000 here). Replace `Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5` by the actual range.
2. **Set a list of indexes N of URLs to copy**: Locate in `Sheet2` the cell at the row just below the last (6 in your example) and the column just to the right of the last (D in your case). Enter the sequence 1,2,... from that cell down.
3. **Pick the Nth URL to copy**: Enter the formula `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,SMALL(Sheet1!$B:$B,D6)-2,0)` in B6. Copy down.

Variations on this can be produced.

Answer (score 0):

We are migrating from [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/). Here is the snippet I used in my phpunit test to compare 2 excel files using `PhpSpreadsheet`:

```
    // compare files
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
    // no need to read styles, we just care about data
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    // load expected file (stored somewhere in the tests directory)
    $spreadsheetExpected = $reader->load($expectedFilePath);
    // load the generated file
    $spreadsheetActual = $reader->load($actualFilePath);
    // loop through 3 pages, indices 0, 1, and 2
    foreach (range(0, 2) as $sheet) {
        // loop through 2 rows
        foreach (range(1, 20) as $row) {
            // loop through first 6 columns
            foreach (['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'] as $column) {
                // find coordination
                $cell = $column . $row;
                // get expected cell value
                $expected = $spreadsheetExpected->getSheet($sheet)->getCell($cell)->getValue();
                // get actual cell value
                $actual = $spreadsheetActual->getSheet($sheet)->getCell($cell)->getValue();
                // compare values, show the sheet and coordination in case of failure 
                $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual, "Mismatch in sheet {$sheet}, cell {$cell}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Apparently this test fails on the first mismatch.